# C# unzip file from azure storage container path

Tags: c#, azure, zip, azure-blob-storage, unzip

I Store one zip file in azure blob storage. now i want to unzip file. in my client application and do some operation on it..

**Note :**  I am using `System.IO.Compression` assembly for this.

`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(myBlobObj.Uri.ToString(), _Destination_Dir);`

It gives me exception path not supported any other way to without to unzip file without downloading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot unzip a blob to another blob (or to a Storage container), as blobs and containers aren't the same as local files / directories, and don't behave the same way. The only way to unzip is to download it from blob storage to somewhere local (such as your VM), unzip to local storage, and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: OP can also operate on streams. That way use of local storage can be avoided.